# How to make this regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, replace

I want to replace all line break (`<br>` or `<br />`) in a string with PHP. What regular expression I should have to do this, using preg_replace?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use regexps to parse or modify HTML. The `<center>` cannot hold it is too late. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3):

Replace `|<br\s*/?>|i` with "a string".

(Note that you can't parse HTML with regex even just for `<br />` — e.g. what if this `<br />` is part of a string in some inline Javascript? Use a parser to get reliable result.)

Answer (score 2):

```
/<br[^>]*>/
```

Should do ... and handles `<br clear="all">` too. (If this is not a requirement, use [KennyTM's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590333/how-to-make-this-regular-expression/2590340#2590340) instead. In all cases you *should* read his disclaimer.)

Comment: <br data-synthesize="<br>" />

Comment: @Williham Totland, not that, no :S

Comment: Using possessive quantifiers: `/<br[^>]*+>/`

Comment: @Geert: <br data-synthesize="<br>" data-xml="<break />" />

Really, I can play this game all day. ;D

Comment: @Williham: sure, you are right, but that's a problem in jensgram's version too. All I wanted to say is that if a character group (`[^>]`) can't consume the character following it (`>`), you should use possessive quantifiers to prevent possible needless backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
$string = str_replace(array('<br>','<br />'),'', $string);
```

Oh, **regex isn't ideal tool for everything**

So if you decide that insisting on using `preg_replace` isn't meaningful anymore, you can use this

Comment: I said using preg_replace, please :-)

Comment: I believe OP wishes to replace all `<br>` AND `<br />` instances.

Comment: @jensgram - overlooked that, ty for hu.

Answer (score 0):

check this if it helps please post back if here is any problem.

```
$str = 'This is a test string<br>.and another string <br>that will replace<br> with <br />';

$pattern = "/<br>/";
$replace = "<br />";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);
```